# Can I select the row of a table and retrieve the name of the table that I am selecting?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `page` and I query this, for instance,

```
SELECT *
FROM page
```

and I access the data each row in this table columns like this `$item->title;`

I want to know if I can select the row of this table and at the same time I can retrieve what name is this table I am selecting? So when I do this,

`echo $item->table_name;` then I get this - **page**

is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could, of course, do something like this:

```
SELECT *, 'page' AS table_name FROM page;
```

Asking what table you obtained a row from doesn't really make a whole lot of sense though.  What would you expect the result to be if you had executed a join?  What about a union of two queries that select different tables?

Comment: good questions! thank you for the answer. I will think carefully on the questions whether I need to do this or not...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there appears to be a PHP [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-tablename.php) to give you the table name of your query. I've never used it, so am not sure how it would work in a join or anything, but it appears to do what you wish at the moment.